# How can I force MediaWiki to respect single line breaks?

Tags: php, mediawiki

By default, MediaWiki ignores single line breaks, treating them as a single space. To insert a new line in a page, you must insert two consecutive line breaks in the source, which results in a new paragraph: `</p><p>`. It's also possible to insert `<br />` directly into the source.

How can I modify the MediaWiki parsing engine so single line breaks in the source are replaced automatically with a `<br />` in the resulting HTML?

(Source: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting)

Comment: yes, you can edit the source anyway you like.

Comment: Point taken – I've rephrased the question and said a prayer to St. Pedanticus. :)

Comment: I've been thinking and there's one thing I can't grasp - what's wrong with the paragraph tags?

Comment: It's a wiki for free verse. Paragraphs aren't semantically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Poem

```
<poem>
Roses are red
Violets are blue
</poem>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<pre></pre>
```

This html tag seems to do the job for me.

Comment: No, don't do this! Reason 1: <pre>-blocks don't appear in normal formatting but wrapped in grey boxes. Reason2: You create <pre>-blocks in Mediawiki not by manually entering the tags but simply by beginning each line that should be wrapped in <pre> with a single space.

Comment: My purpose is to store some useful sql scripts on wiki. And copy/paste to from Sql Server or a text editor must be instant. No way I am going to insert html tags one way and remove them the other. And I don't want to install a poetic extension. Surrounding my code with <pre></pre> looks good and I don't care about the text being displayed in a box.

Answer (score 2):

You could write [an extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aExtensions) that adds br tags to newlines when parsing the wikicode. However, you'd have to be very careful - you don't want *every* newline in the wikicode to actually be a br tag, do you?

Edit: you don't want every newline to be a br tag, because not every newline in the wikicode should actually be a linebreak. For example, a table:

```
{|
|+ The table's caption
|-
|Cell 1
|Cell 2
|-
|Cell A
|Cell B
|}
```

It would turn quite messy if you added br tags into the table code.

Comment: What are the downsides to converting newlines to <br>s?

Comment: The whole point of Wiki markup is to allow users to edit something that looks like text, instead of raw HTML.  Adding <br>'s to every single line defeats the point.

Comment: @meetar: for example, a table. I've edited the answer to provide an example.

Comment: @jpatokal: I suppose that is why the asker wants to have it done in the parser

Comment: @jpatokal Yes, I want to avoid HTML in the source. I've edited the question to clarify that point.